# Onclick not working on Mobile view

Tags: javascript, css

I'm new to this website. I would like to know few awesome tricks. I would like to know about the onclick function. for some reason it doesn't work in mobile. My code is:

```
<a class="buttonContact" href="mailto:...@gmail.com%20?subject=Regarding:" 
onclick="window.open('...url...')">Contact Me</a>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [ask]  - it is important to mention Expected and Actual result

Comment: Thank you , but the issue is that , because of onclick function. mailto is not working.
Can you help me improve the code! :)

Comment: Try `<a class="buttonContact" href="mailto:...@gmail.com%20?subject=Regarding:">Contact Me</a>` and `document.querySelector(".buttonContact").addEventListener("click", function() { setTimeout(function() { window.open("url","newWin","width=800,height=400"),500)});`

Comment: Code is still not working

Comment: Typo in my code. Try this: `window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector(".buttonContact").addEventListener("click", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.open("https://www.google.com", "newWin", "width=800,height=400")
    }, 500);
  });
}`